# Symfony 4 Event Dispatcher - is there some solution how to filter value with Event Dispatcher? (like wordpress "add_filter" function)

Tags: wordpress, symfony, events, symfony-eventdispatcher

is there some solution how to filter value/values with Symfony Event Dispatcher like wordpress with add_filter that returns filtered value?
Maybe store properties in Event and edit them with subscriber?

Comment: Working both in Symfony and WordPress and having experience with Joomla filtering plugins, I understand your question, and in fact I already answered, but a Symfony dev with less experienced with filters would probably have a hard time understand. You should probably expand the description of what you need to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution you proposed is the best I can think of. There is no "native" mechanism intended to post-process a value like in WordPress filters or Joomla plugins.

If you dispatch a custom event and populate with the object you want to "filter" you can easily add a subscriber to do what you mean. As objects are always passed by reference, any alteration to the object will be propagated in the controller.

E.g.

controller:

```
$product = $this->productRepository->get($someId);
$this->eventDispacther->dispatch(
    BeforeDisplayEvent::class,
    new BeforeDisplayEvent($product)
)

return $this->render('product.html.twig', ['product' => $product]);
```

subscriber:

```
public function alterProduct(BeforeDisplayEvent $event)
{
    $product->setSomething($this->yourFilter($product));
}
```

Comment: I see that you are a Joomla developer, but you have not extended your Stack Exchange citizenship to [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  Please join us and help us to resolve some of our unresolved questions.

Comment: @mickmackusa thank you. I joined it but I cannot guarantee I'll have the time / skill to resolve unresolved questions :-)

Comment: Time will tell.